# Laravel uploading file Unable to write in directory

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I'm uploading files in my system and it works locally where am using windows and xampp but when hosting where am using an Ubuntu stack my file is not being uploaded. I'm getting an error that it cannot be written in the 'system' directory which is within the public folder. This is my code

```
 $destinationPath = public_path().'/system'; // upload path
  $extension = Request::file('add_students')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting excel extension
  // dd($extension);
  $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing excel file
  $file=Request::file('add_students')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
  $path=$file->getRealPath();
```

after looking for solutions I found out that I should make my directory writable so I ran the following command in putty

`chmod 770 /var/www/html/public/system`

but still even after that am getting an error `Unable to write in the "/var/www/html/public/system" directory`.

I'm using laravel 5 and my host is digital ocean. Thanks

Comment: try `chmod 755  /var/www/html/public/system and chown www-data:www-data  /var/www/html/public/system`

Comment: Check and print the destination path ant give full permission 777 just to test first then change to 755

Comment: Are you on apache server?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`chmod 755 /var/www/html/public/system` and  `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/public/system` as stated by @JLPuro works perfectly. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: One might want to add -R flag to do this recursively. Didn't work for me until I added the flag. **chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/dir**

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Centos-7 Then use

```
sudo find directory_name -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find directory_name -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

sudo chown -R apache:apache var/www/html/directory_name
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t directory_name
```

Where directory_name is the main directory of you Project.

Comment: Thank you
sudo chown -R apache:apache var/www/html/directory_name should be sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/directory_name

Answer (score 3):

permission for **folder** `sudo chmod 777./(folder name)`

for **file** `sudo chmod 777 -R ./(file name)`

Comment: This will be disaster, don't use 777 please .This gives permission to everyone read, write even delete. This command actually feed a hacker by you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have to create a directory use this:

```
use File;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
```

use this in controller

```
if (!file_exists(public_path().'system')) {            
                if(File::makeDirectory(public_path().'system',0777,true)){                
                  }
                }
```

use this in your function