# Unable to write in laravel public folder

Tags: linux, laravel

I have a problem writing on /var/www/html/app/public/upload/ on linux server and also I got this error when execute chown "changing ownership o/var/www/html/app/public/upload/: Operation not permitted"

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836602/laravel-uploading-file-unable-to-write-in-directory

Answer (score 0):

you need to give read and write permissions to the webserver for storage, cache, and any other directories the webserver needs to upload or write to (depending on your situation), so run the following commands(from the project working directory)

> sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
>
> sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

and also if you are using a storage link then don't forget to run the following command

> php artisan storage:link